# How to readin javascript code into the geth console?

Tags: go-ethereum, command-line

In the [contracts tutorial](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Contract-Tutorial#compiling-your-contract), quite a long piece of code is provided on the geth console to the client:

```
[...]
function(e, contract){
  if(!e) {

    if(!contract.address) {
      console.log("Contract transaction send: TransactionHash: " + contract.transactionHash + " waiting to be mined...");

    } else {
      console.log("Contract mined! Address: " + contract.address);
      console.log(contract);
    }

  }
}
```

How could I provide this `function` definition from an external file to the console?, such that I don't have to write it all on the console which is quite inconveniente i find.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [loadScript](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/JavaScript-Console#loadscript) function in geth takes an external JS file and executes it.

Example usage:

```
//somefile.js
function foo() {...};
```

In console:

```
loadScript('somefile.js');
foo();
```

It's loaded as if every line was executed directly, like node.js .load

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I've added more detail.